# Fill a week days in a table with preceding Sundays value

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I need a table that displays the preceding Sundays value for the days in the week. The table is built from another table which has values for every day. I have day of week (as a number)  and month included in the table. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Sun   100

Mon   100

Tues   100

Wed   100

Thurs   100

Fri   100

Sat   100

Sun   300

Mon   300

Tues   300

Thanks
I

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have day of the week as a number,  from a date dimension table.

I managed to to do it, by joining my fact to the date dimension table and filtering on Sunday. Then joining my date dimension back to this newly created table. So i had values for Sunday and nulls for the rest of the week. I then used a case statement with a lag:

`(case when sum(b.Delivery_Value) is null then
lag(sum(b.Delivery_Value),a.day_of_week - 1) over (order by a.date_key asc)
else sum(b.Delivery_Value) end)`

Basically subtracting one from the day of the week so the lag always goes back to Sunday.

Not sure if its the best way.